# print statements are not appearing in GAE

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Running GAE application in dev(dev_appserver.py). Print statements are not showing when I run, statements are showing when I kill (Ctrl+C) the application.

Its a very simple application.

dev_appserver command:

```
python dev_appserver.py --skip_sdk_update_check=yes C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb
```

Output: Print statement is not appearing.

```
INFO     2017-07-05 10:33:54,759 devappserver2.py:116] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-07-05 10:33:54,875 api_server.py:297] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53833
INFO     2017-07-05 10:33:54,891 dispatcher.py:209] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-07-05 10:33:54,907 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2017-07-05 10:33:59,188 module.py:809] default: "GET /fb/getdim HTTP/1.1" 200 40
```

Calling Function:

```
class get_dim(webapp.RequestHandler):

    _apptitle      = None
    _projectid     = None
    _projectnumber = None


    def get(self):
        #bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME', app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
        cfg=appsettings()
        self.response.write("Enter into getdim")
        for i in cfg._templates:

            id=int(i['_id'])

            if id == 1:
                self.response.write("Enter into if statement")
                fbutils._getDim(int(i['_id']),i['_app_id'],i['_app_secret'],i['_access_token'],i['_ad_acct'],i['_filename'],i['_gcsbucket'],cfg)
```

Actual Function:

```
def _getDim(idno,app_id,app_secret,access_token,ad_acct,file_name,bucket_nm,cfg):
  try:
    print "Hi This is test message"
  except:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
```

Answer (score 1):

The most like cause of this is that your operating system is not flushing the buffer that your print statements are being written to until after dev server process has finished.

Use the [logging package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to have output produced while the dev server is running.

```
import logging

def _getDim(idno,app_id,app_secret,access_token,ad_acct,file_name,bucket_nm,cfg):
  try:
    logging.info("Hi This is test message")
  except:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    logging.exception('Something went wrong.')
```

By default the dev server suppresses log messages with a level less than `info`, but you can control this by passing the [--log_level](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command) parameter to the dev server.

```
python dev_appserver.py --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --log_level=debug C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb
```

Comment: Thanks Snakecharmerb. Option "--log_level=debug" is not helping in my case. OS is windows 10. Some times it was running fine. some times facing lot of issues like print statement is not displaying and some times not sure whether it ran the function or not it wont give any kind of response.logging.info showing the messages.